# How to convert an NSData to const char *?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I am trying to convert a NSData object with audio data to a const char *. I have to do this because the API I am trying to call expects const char *. But I am unable to do so as

```
const char * stream = [data bytes]; //won't compile
```

also

```
const char * stream = (const char *)[data bytes];
```

will compile but will only have the first 2 bytes for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want more concrete help, you'll have to be more specific about what problem you're trying to solve by passing NSData to an API that wants a `const char*`.

Comment: alright, basically I need the API to set a hex stream for me. So maybe the question is how to convert NSData to const char * that encodes a hex stream? Is that more clear?

Comment: Are you putting it into a hex stream to read it out again later (reconstruct the object), or to print to the screen? The other end matters for this question.

Comment: To reconstruct the object I would say

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the NSData you are loading is originally a string, you can try something like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *chars = [string UTF8String];
```

This will first convert the NSData to a NSString, and then convert the NSString to const char pointer.

### Update

Since you are trying to just encode the data as a hex string, take a look at this thread:

[How to convert an NSData into an NSString Hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string)

It should look something like this:

```
NSUInteger capacity = data.length * 2;
NSMutableString *sbuf = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:capacity];
const unsigned char *buf = data.bytes;
NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
{
  [sbuf appendFormat:@"%02X", (NSUInteger)buf[i]];
}
const char *chars = [sbuf UTF8String];
```

Comment: I tried this too. It is not working as string will always be nil. Maybe the thing is that the NSData is extracted from audio files.

Comment: I just updated the answer, take a look at the link I added

Comment: The answers in that link always all have steps that involves doing const char * stream = (const char *)[data bytes]; which already null terminates the data.

Comment: @MongoHooli look at the code I just posted, it should look something like that

Answer (score 0):

`const char*` is assumed to point at a null-terminated string, so the first null character in the `NSData` object will terminate the string.

Performing this conversion using a cast does not make sense out of context, since it's just asking the API to interpret an NSData as a `const char*`.

If you are trying to pass an NSData to an API that wants `const char*`, you are likely to be using the wrong API for your purpose, or you need to re-encode your data before using the API.

**Update: Based on the OP's comment, he wants to encode the data to decode it later.**

There are a variety of different solutions for this, but one simple possibility is to `base64` encode the data using the [API method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1412739-base64encodeddatawithoptions?language=objc). You could then `base64` decode it using the symmmetric [API method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410081-initwithbase64encodedstring?language=objc). You could then convert the resulting `NSString` to `const char*` using the approach suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003766/391161).